# bit shifting and weird output

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

so im stumped on the results im getting so if anyone can explain whats happen and what i need to fix here. so the goal is that i shift (i) 1 bit at a time, until p & i = j which should look like this in binary

```
 101011100 & 1 != 100 
 101011100 & 10 != 100
 101011100 & 100 != 100 //true
```

but i get i jumping way past p and rotates pos and neg every other number
here is my code:

```
int i=1;
int p= // some memmory addres for this case lets just say p = 101011100
int j=1;
while(p&i != 1<j){

i=i+(i<1);
printf("i:%d\n",i);
}
```

Comment: why have you used `j<3` in the condition part?

Comment: I have noooo clue what that loop is trying to accomplish.  `i = 1` forever!

Comment: Shift operators are `>>` and `<<` (double angle brackets).

Comment: @AswinMurugesh The love operator. Love heals all.

Comment: ok i had << i must of deleted a < when pasting the code but thats not my problem

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence

Answer (score 0):

To check for the condition `p&i!=j`, the code i would suggest is:

```
int i=1;
int p = //binary
int j = 4;
while((p&i)!=j)
{
    i = i<<1;
    printf("i: %d\n",i);
    //Alter j value if needed
}
```

And as per the example provided the j value is 100. So, I prefer j to be 4 in such case, as decimal equivalent of 100 is 4.

Comment: Beware the precedence of `&` vs. `!=`.  You most assuredly do not want `(p & i != j)`. You more likely want `((p & i) != j)`.

Comment: ya but i<< doesnt work for me i had to do i=(i+(i<<1)), i get that it equals decimal of 4 but when i print it out its like 18020304 then next number is  -21939402 and repeats that

Comment: @user1547386: That is because the number goes beyond the range of an int

Comment: but i think i would expect the i to go 1,2,4,8 ..ect not jump straight  > then 1million

Comment: @user1547386  That is what happens in the code that i have put

Comment: hmmm idk then, thats what i expect but its not happening, but thx for the help.

Comment: @user1547386  idk? and that is what should happen here. What is the value that you are getting?

Comment: i get number > 1million then they rotate pos to neg numbers

Comment: @user1547386 that is because the value of `p&i` does not match with the value at j.   What do you have as j value?

Answer (score 0):

You can code in hex, or in binary, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void print_binary(unsigned short x)
{
    for (int b = 32768; b != 0; b /= 2)
    {
        printf("%d", (b & x) != 0);
        x &= ~b;
    }
}

static unsigned short scan_binary(char const *binary)
{
    unsigned short u = 0;
    char c;
    while ((c = *binary++) != '\0')
    {
        /* GIGO: if it isn't a '0' or a '1', you get what you deserve! */
        u = (u << 1) | (c - '0');
    }
    return u;
}

int main(void)
{
    /* Working in hex - simpler */
    int p = 0x15C;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        if ((p & (1 << i)) == 0x04)
            printf("Shift %d yields 0x%.4X from 0x%.4X and 0x%.4X\n",
                   i, (p & (1 << i)), p, (1 << i));
    }

    /* Working in binary - harder */
    char b1[] = "101011100";
    char b2[] = "100";
    unsigned u1 = scan_binary(b1);
    unsigned u2 = scan_binary(b2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        if ((u1 & (1 << i)) == u2)
        {
            printf("Shift %d yields ", i);
            print_binary(p & (1 << i));
            printf(" from ");
            print_binary(u1);
            printf(" and ");
            print_binary(1 << i);
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Shift 2 yields 0x0004 from 0x015C and 0x0004
Shift 2 yields 0000000000000100 from 0000000101011100 and 0000000000000100
```

One reason not to use binary is that it produces very long strings of digits.